# Stop a motion tween in flash cs6

Tags: flash, animation, adobe, flash-cs6

i have couple of movie animation on my flash stage which are on loop,
and there is this one motion tween which i have insert from define presets and i want to stop that motion tween after the first action, only that motion tween.

i have tried

> stop();

which has stopped all the animations and i have tried

> movieclipname.stop();

and this won't work

please give yourl feed back

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Afaik we must put the motion tween inside a movieclip and your second code should work. Maybe make sure you gave the 'instance name' to the movie clip after you put it on the stage?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
"myMovieClip" is the name of your movie clip

```
myMovieClip.stop();
```

Also this is assuming that your tween is already a movie clip.